# I need to transfer XML data into Oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to import data from an XML file to table in Oracle. I am using TOAD

I have followed the below Oracle forum thread for the same:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2182669

The XML file is as below(Example2.xml;same as the sited in forum just changed the name):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <ACCOUNT_HEADER_ACK>
 <HEADER>
 <STATUS_CODE>100</STATUS_CODE>
 <STATUS_REMARKS>check</STATUS_REMARKS>
 </HEADER>
 <DETAILS> 
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>2</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 <REMARKS>rp polytechnic</REMARKS>
 </DETAIL>
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>3</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 <REMARKS>rp polytechnic administration</REMARKS>
 </DETAIL>
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>4</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 <REMARKS>rp polytechnic finance</REMARKS>
 </DETAIL>
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>5</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 <REMARKS>rp polytechnic logistics</REMARKS>
 </DETAIL>
 </DETAILS>
 <HEADER>
 <STATUS_CODE>500</STATUS_CODE>
 <STATUS_REMARKS>process exception</STATUS_REMARKS>
 </HEADER>
 <DETAILS> 
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>20</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 <REMARKS> base polytechnic</REMARKS>
 </DETAIL>
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>30</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 </DETAIL>
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>40</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 <REMARKS> base polytechnic finance</REMARKS>
 </DETAIL>
 <DETAIL> 
 <SEGMENT_NUMBER>50</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
 <REMARKS> base polytechnic logistics</REMARKS>
 </DETAIL>
 </DETAILS>
 </ACCOUNT_HEADER_ACK>
```

I have created the directories and tables where I intend to fetch the data:

```
create directory test_direc as 'C:\Documents and Settings\adeb01\Desktop'

create table xxrp_acct_details(
segment_number number,
status_code    number,
status_remarks varchar2(100),
remarks        varchar2(100)
);
```

After creating tables and directories I am running this:

```
DECLARE

 acct_doc xmltype := xmltype( bfilename('test_direc','Example2.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8') );

BEGIN

 insert into xxrp_acct_details (status_code, status_remarks, segment_number, remarks)
 select x.*
 from xmltable(
  'for $i in /ACCOUNT_HEADER_ACK/HEADER
   return 
    for $j in $i/following-sibling::DETAILS[1]/DETAIL
    return element r {$i, $j}'
  passing acct_doc
  columns status_code    number        path 'HEADER/STATUS_CODE',
          status_remarks varchar2(100) path 'HEADER/STATUS_REMARKS',
          segment_number number        path 'DETAIL/SEGMENT_NUMBER',
          remarks        varchar2(100) path 'DETAIL/REMARKS'
 ) x
 ;

END;
```

When I run this, I am getting error as:

```
ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 296
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

I have a feeling control files can be an issue because I didn't create any.

========================================================

In my previous code the problem was connection was not getting built properly. 
What I did now is I am storing the entire XML into a file in the declaration and I am calling it.
However I am encountering the following error:
ORA-06550: line 14, column 19:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

I changed my code this way:

```
DECLARE
 v_outputfile    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('\home\apradh01\','Example2.xml','w');


BEGIN

 insert into xxrp_acct_details (status_code, status_remarks, segment_number, remarks)
 select x.*
 from xmltable(
  'for $i in /ACCOUNT_HEADER_ACK/HEADER
   return 
    for $j in $i/following-sibling::DETAILS[1]/DETAIL
    return element r {$i, $j}'
  passing XMLTYPE(v_outputfile)
  columns status_code    number        path 'HEADER/STATUS_CODE',
          status_remarks varchar2(100) path 'HEADER/STATUS_REMARKS',
          segment_number number        path 'DETAIL/SEGMENT_NUMBER',
          remarks        varchar2(100) path 'DETAIL/REMARKS'
 ) x
 ;

END;
```

=================================================

Okay so there is some connection issue I am certain cause when I am modifying my code like below (ie instead of reading the XML content from a file I am manually entering it) it's working fine:

```
DECLARE

BEGIN

 insert into xxrp_acct_details (status_code, status_remarks, segment_number, remarks)
 select x.*
 from xmltable(
  'for $i in /ACCOUNT_HEADER_ACK/HEADER
   return 
    for $j in $i/following-sibling::DETAILS[1]/DETAIL
    return element r {$i, $j}'
  passing XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ACCOUNT_HEADER_ACK>
<HEADER>
<STATUS_CODE>100</STATUS_CODE>
<STATUS_REMARKS>check</STATUS_REMARKS>
</HEADER>
<DETAILS> 
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>2</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
<REMARKS>rp polytechnic</REMARKS>
</DETAIL>
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>3</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
<REMARKS>rp polytechnic administration</REMARKS>
</DETAIL>
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>4</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
<REMARKS>rp polytechnic finance</REMARKS>
</DETAIL>
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>5</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
<REMARKS>rp polytechnic logistics</REMARKS>
</DETAIL>
</DETAILS>
<HEADER>
<STATUS_CODE>500</STATUS_CODE>
<STATUS_REMARKS>process exception</STATUS_REMARKS>
</HEADER>
<DETAILS> 
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>20</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
<REMARKS> base polytechnic</REMARKS>
</DETAIL>
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>30</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
</DETAIL>
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>40</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
<REMARKS> base polytechnic finance</REMARKS>
</DETAIL>
<DETAIL> 
<SEGMENT_NUMBER>50</SEGMENT_NUMBER>
<REMARKS> base polytechnic logistics</REMARKS>
</DETAIL>
</DETAILS>
</ACCOUNT_HEADER_ACK>'
)
  columns status_code    number        path 'HEADER/STATUS_CODE',
          status_remarks varchar2(100) path 'HEADER/STATUS_REMARKS',
          segment_number number        path 'DETAIL/SEGMENT_NUMBER',
          remarks        varchar2(100) path 'DETAIL/REMARKS'
 ) x
 ;

END;
```

So one relief my code for picking out XML data and transfering it to table is correct
Now the only problem is how should I transfer the filename instead of manually entering the XML

I feel we can utilize UTL_FILE to read the content of the file and then storing & passing it alongside

```
acct_doc xmltype := xmltype( bfilename('TEST_DIR','acct.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8') );
```

Any suggestions...

Comment: Is the database running on your local PC, or on a server somewhere else?

Comment: it is running on a server

Comment: I know what you might be getting at, that I am giving my local machine's path not the server's...but its not that. I am working on client's remote machine...I have given the path of the remote machine

Comment: So the path `C:\Documents and Settings\adeb01\Desktop` does exist on the database server? And it's accessible to everyone, or at least to whichever account Oracle is running under? (I'm not 100% sure how that works under Windows, I just realised!). Home directories are usually restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your directory with `create directory test_direc ...`, which means you use a non-quoted identifier, which is good; but that means it's stored in the data dictionary with the name in uppercase. If you query the `all_directories` view as `TEST_DIREC`. So you need to use that uppercase name when you pass the directory name as a string:

```
bfilename('TEST_DIREC','Example2.xml')
```

Apart from that, what you have shown works; you don't really need a PL/SQL block though, you could use a plain SQL insert statement and supply the file directly in the `passing` clause:

```
passing xmltype( bfilename('TEST_DIREC','Example2.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8') )
```

This assumes the directory you're pointing to, `C:\Documents and Settings\adeb01\Desktop`, is on the same machine the database itself is running on, and that Oracle can see it. You can only access directories on the server, not on any clients that are connected to it - that's part of the security model. From [the `create directory` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_5007.htm):

> A directory object specifies an alias for a directory on the **server file system** ...

... and whichever account is running the Oracle database has to have operating system permission to access that directory, which might not be the case if it's under your personal account.

If the file is currently on your PC and the database is somewhere else, you will need to copy the file to the server - to a directory that Oracle has permission to access - and create your Oracle directory object pointing to that server directory.

Comment: @AmritaDeb - I've updated the answer with a note about the file location. It has to be on the server, not on your local PC, I'm afraid.

Comment: I modified my directory to include

Comment: I modified my directory:
`create or replace directory test_direc as '\home\apradh01\'`
This directory is accessible by Oracle...but I am still facing the same issue

Comment: Have you granted permissions on the directory object to the user you're running the insert as?